# почему программа не видит часть кода?

Tags: python

```
playAgain = "да"
while playAgain == "да":
    displayIntro()
    print("Остаться на месте или бежать к двери?")
    choice1 = input().lower     
    if choice1 == "остаться":
          print("Вас парализовал страх и вы не смогли сдвинуться с места.Вас убили.")
                   
    elif choice1 == "бежать":
          print('''Преодолев страх, вы все же решаете попытаться спастись
                            и бежите к заветной двери''')
    doorNumber = chooseDoor()
    checkdoor(doorNumber)


    print("Попытаете удачу еще раз? (да или нет)")
    playAgain = input()
```

Пишу игру, в которой игрок должен выбрать дверь, чтобы спастись. Функции работают, но часть с if, где "бежать" и "остаться" не работает. Программа ее просто пропускает. Может с отступами проблема? Как правильно написать эту часть кода, чтобы при слове "остаться", программа заканчивалась, а при "бежать" работала дальше?

Comment: choice1 = input().lower()

Comment: У вас функция без скобок, должно быть  .lower()

Comment: Спасибо. Такие мелкие детали стопорят всю программу

Comment: Стопорят программу не мелкие детали, а неумение пользоваться отладчиком. Всегда, при первых сомнениях запускайте отладчик и сравнивайте ваши представления в реальностью.

Comment: Да можно и без отладчика - просто печатать переменные, которые вы проверяете через `if`, прямо перед проверкой. И сразу всё сразу становится понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Расскажу как отладить программу вроде вашей.

Запускаете отладчик. Да он текстовый, простецкий, зато он есть везде где есть Питон. Конечно вам будет удобнее пользоваться отладчиком, который есть в вашей среде разработки. Но пока так. Отладчик останавливается на первой строке программы:

> ```
> $ python -m pdb game.py
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py(4)<module>()
> -> def displayIntro():
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Оглядимся вокруг. Команда `ll` выводит код:

> ```
> @(Pdb) ll
>   1       # coding=utf-8
>   2   
>   3   
>   4  ->   def displayIntro():
>   5           pass
>   6   
>   7   
>   8       playAgain = "да"
>   9       while playAgain == "да":
>  10           displayIntro()
>  11           print("Остаться на месте или бежать к двери?")
>  12           choice1 = input().lower
>  13           if choice1 == "остаться":
>  14                 print("Вас парализовал страх и вы не смогли сдвинуться с места.Вас убили.")
>  15
>  16           elif choice1 == "бежать":
>  17                 print('''Преодолев страх, вы все же решаете попытаться спастись
>  18                                   и бежите к заветной двери''')
>  19           doorNumber = chooseDoor()
>  20           checkdoor(doorNumber)
>  21   
>  22   
>  23           print("Попытаете удачу еще раз? (да или нет)")
>  24           playAgain = input()
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Сделаем шаг. Команда `n` выполняет один оператор и показывает следующий:

> ```
> @(Pdb) n
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/game.py(8)<module>()
> -> playAgain = "да"
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Ещё шаг:

> ```
> @(Pdb) n
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py(9)<module>()
> -> while playAgain == "да":
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Что в переменной `playAgain`?

> ```
> @(Pdb) p playAgain
> 'да'
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Шагаем дальше:

> ```
> @(Pdb) n
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/game.py(9)<module>()
> -> while playAgain == "да":
> @(Pdb) n
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/game.py(10)<module>()
> -> displayIntro()
> @(Pdb) n
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/game.py(11)<module>()
> -> print("Остаться на месте или бежать к двери?")
> @(Pdb) n
> Остаться на месте или бежать к двери?
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/game.py(12)<module>()
> -> choice1 = input().lower
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Дошли до ввода. Надо сделать шаг и ввести строку. Вводим 'остаться':

> ```
> @(Pdb) n
> остаться
> > /home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/game.py(13)<module>()
> -> if choice1 == "остаться":
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Что попало в переменную `choice1`?

> ```
> @(Pdb) p choice1
> <built-in method lower of str object at 0x7f1bb756ff30>
> @(Pdb)
> ```

Чепуха какая-то! Там не строка, а функция. Читаем код - пропущены скобки `()` - вызов функции:

> ```
> @(Pdb) l
>   8       playAgain = "да"
>   9       while playAgain == "да":
>  10           displayIntro()
>  11           print("Остаться на месте или бежать к двери?")
>  12           choice1 = input().lower
>  13  ->       if choice1 == "остаться":
>  14                 print("Вас парализовал страх и вы не смогли сдвинуться с места.Вас убили.")
>  15   
>  16           elif choice1 == "бежать":
>  17                 print('''Преодолев страх, вы все же решаете попытаться спастись
>  18                               и бежите к заветной двери''')
> @(Pdb)
> ```